# How can I export a model with its textures applied?

Tags: export, gltf, packed-data

I have a blender model that is 7Mb, a laptop with 4 image textures applied to it. I am trying to export it to use in [Google Poly](https://poly.google.com/).

When I follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEP34CbPWUo) to export as a **.fbx**, the resulting **.fbx** file is 28Kb and doesn't display textures once I upload it to Poly.

I tried using the **gITF 2.0 export**, but again, the resulting file was 16Kb.

As a last resort, I exported as **.obj** (the last format Blender can export to that Poly accepts), but the resulting .obj and /mtl files were 1Kb and 5Kb.

The other questions or tutorials I found did not apply to my situation, since I am using UV photographic textures in Cycles.

**Is there a way to export a model and its UV textures to .obj, .gITF, .glb or .fbx from Blender?**

Comment: Maybe this tool might solve yur problem
https://blendermarket.com/products/glb-texture-tools

Answer (score 5):

The most likely explanations for why your textures are not exporting would be that (a) the textures are not in an image format supported by the export format, or (b) the material is not configured in a way that the export format's addon understands.

In the case of glTF 2.0 (I can't comment on FBX or OBJ), images must be in PNG or JPG format to be exported. The material should typically use the Principled BSDF material — arbitrary material node graphs cannot be exported from Blender to any format.

For full details on how to configure your materials for correct export from Blender, see the [documentation of the Blender glTF exporter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html). In particular, this is a standard material setup with a base color texture:

[image: displays an Image Texture node connected to the 'Base Color' socket of a Principled BSDF material, in Blender]